# Showing custom fields of custom post type in a date ordered list on a page

Tags: date, calendar, advanced-custom-fields

I'm struggling with this. I add multiple custom field values: in this case event dates with their title and location to all my projects (custom post type) and want to display them in a table together on a page called Calendar. I tried to query the posts but then the custom fields will show as groups together, and not as a date ordered list.

The event titles match the post title in this case.

My question is: what would be the best solution? Creating all the event dates as custom fields within the posts and then show them all together on a single page called calendar, or create them all in a calendar page and then filter those on title to show only the relevant ones in a single post that match the page title?

The event name is taken from a post object, which seemed the best solution for the scenario where all events are created on the same page, but other wise I might use just the post title.

Hope there is someone to help!

My code for the calendar (the part with upcoming dates):

```
<div class="Rtable upcoming  Rtable--collapse">


    <?php $outs = array(); if( have_rows('events') ):  ?>
    
    
    <?php while ( have_rows('events') ) : the_row();  ob_start();

                                            // Get sub field values.
                                            $date = get_sub_field('date');    
                                            $location = get_sub_field('location');
                                            $website = get_sub_field('website');
                                            $title = get_sub_field('title');
                                            $premiere = get_sub_field('premiere');
                                            $event = get_sub_field('date', false, false);
                                            $today = strtotime(date('Ymd'));
                                            $upcoming = strtotime($event);
                                            $datefin = new DateTime($event); ?>
 
<?php if ($upcoming >=$today): ?>
    
    
    
    
    <div class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--head <?php if( get_sub_field('premiere') == 'yes' ): ?>premiere <?php endif; ?>">

        <?php if( get_sub_field('date') ): ?><?php the_sub_field('date'); ?><?php endif; ?>

    </div>



    <div class="Rtable-cell table-project-title"><?php if( get_sub_field('premiere') == 'yes' ): ?><span style="color: var(--magenta);">premiere:</span> <?php endif; ?>
    
        <?php if( $title ): ?><?php foreach( $title as $post ): 

                                                              // Setup this post for WP functions (variable must be named $post).
                                                              setup_postdata($post); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <?php endforeach; ?> <?php 
                                                          // Reset the global post object so that the rest of the page works correctly.
                                                          wp_reset_postdata(); ?> <?php endif; ?>
    
    
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="Rtable-cell"><?php if( get_sub_field('location') ): ?><?php the_sub_field('location'); ?><?php endif; ?></div>
    <div class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--foot"><?php if( get_sub_field('website') ): ?><a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $website ); ?>" target="_blank">Tickets</a> <?php endif; ?></div>


  
   <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $outs[] = ob_get_clean(); endwhile; ?>


    <?php
        else :
        endif;
        $outs = array_reverse($outs);
        echo implode($outs);
        ?>

</div><!-- UPCOMING END -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, to query by the custom field date. Result here:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Calendar

*/

get_header();
?>

<?php get_header();
?>

<div class="content-header yellow">

    <h1><?php the_title();
?></h1>

</div>

<!-- Kalender -->

<div class="yellow content">

    <div class="Rtable upcoming  Rtable--collapse">

        <?php

// Create an empty array for storage
$post_data = array();

// Set arguments for your query
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'projects',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1
);

// Do our query with any arguments from above
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // Setup our repeater
        if ( have_rows( 'events' ) ):
        while ( have_rows( 'events' ) ) : the_row();
        // Optional - Only get posts that match a true false within our repeater

        $event = get_sub_field( 'date', false, false );
        $today = strtotime( date( 'Ymd' ) );
        $upcoming = strtotime( $event );
        $datefin = new DateTime( $event );
     
        

        if ( $upcoming >= $today ) {

            // Build our array with the data we need using key => value
            $post_data[] = array(
                'url' => get_the_permalink(),
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'date'  => get_sub_field( 'date' ),
                'location'  => get_sub_field( 'location' ),
                'website'  => get_sub_field( 'website' ),

            );

        }
        endwhile;
        endif;
    }
} ?>



        <?php // Custom function to use in our sort to list the items by date

function subval_sort( $a, $b ) {
    if ( $a['date'] == $b['date'] )
    return 0;
    return $a['date'] < $b['date'] ? -1 : 1;
}

// Sort our multidimensional array by sub array value
usort( $post_data, 'subval_sort' );

// We can now work our data normally through easy to access methods
foreach ( $post_data as $post ) {
    ?>

        <div class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--head <?php if( get_sub_field('premiere') == 'yes' ): ?>premiere <?php endif; ?>">

            <?php   $format_in = 'm/d/Y';
    // the format your value is saved in ( set in the field options )
    $format_out = 'd/m/Y';
    // the format you want to end up with

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format_in, $post['date'] );

    echo $date->format( $format_out ) . '&nbsp; ' ;
    ?>

        </div>

        <div class="Rtable-cell table-project-title"><?php if ( get_sub_field( 'premiere' ) == 'yes' ): ?><span style="color: var(--magenta);">premiere:</span> <?php endif;
    ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $post['url']; ?> ">

                <?php
    echo $post['title'] . '&nbsp; ' ;
    ?>

            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="Rtable-cell">

            <?php echo $post['location'] . '&nbsp; ' ;
    
    ?>

        </div>

        <div class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--foot">

            <a class="button" href="<?php
    echo $post['website']; ?> ">

                tickets
            </a>
        </div>

        <?php }
    ?>


    </div>


</div>

<?php get_footer();
    ?>
```